# Can I display the width of a div increased with animate() using a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, html, jquery-animate, width

Is it possible to use animate() to increase a div's width dynamically
and display this in a variable?

I've tried several things, but the variable still displays the original width of the div (wich is zero) So it's not being updated.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="button2">Add width</a>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, 500);
});

var width = $('#content').width();
$("#msg").html(width);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7asv2/)

So I would like to know how I can accomplish this. Should I write a update function for the variable or is there a more simple way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279196/animate-jquery-event-handler-in-the-middle-of-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**. You can provide a `complete` function in your animate function:

```
$('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, 500, function () {
      var width = $('#content').width();
      $("#msg").html(width);
});
```

Alternatively, use overloaded method with two parameters (attributes and options):

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, {
        step: function () {
            var width = $('#content').width();
            $("#msg").html(width);
        }
    })
});
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7asv2/5/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, 500, function() {
        var width = $('#content').width();
        $("#msg").html(width);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use animate callback..

Your code checks and updates the width only once - in the beginning.
You must do it every time the animation updates the width of content.
For that you could use the animate method's callback.

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, 500, function(){
        var width = $('#content').width();
        $("#msg").html(width);
    });
});
```

Callback is a function passed as the third parameter of 'animate' and it is called when the animation finishes.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7asv2/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function which es called on any step of the animation

```
$('#content').animate({
        width: '+=40'
    }, {
        step: function (w) {
            msg.html(w);
        },
        duration: 500,
        easing: "linear"
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy7S4/)